# Check forwarding queue occupation on router

Tags: linux, forwarding, openwrt

I have a router forwarding traffic from a network to another and I need to know when the packet queue (in the receiving side/interface - rx) occupation is close to its maximum capacity.

However, after analysing the following files (linux filesystem):

- **tcp_mem/tcp_rmem/tcp_wmem** in /proc/sys/net/ipv4
- **tx_queue_len** in /sys/class/net/(interface)
- **sockstat** in /proc/net

I concluded these files would only be relevant for my problem if the router was the destination or source of the TCP packets. So, as I discussed with a professor, these metrics are not relevant in a forwarding situation, as the packets do not go to the TCP queues.

If that's true, then where can I find information on forwarding queue's current occupation and its maximum occupation, if there's any information on the matter?

Comment: have a look there, I'm sure this can help your hidden goals: http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Traffic-Control-HOWTO/ . While quite old documentation, it's mostly still relevant as is (except for ingress where IMQ was replaced with [IFB](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/ifb))

Answer (score 1):

This router -- is it yours?  Is it routing by simply using Linux networking?  If so, you probably want to replace it with an actual router, unless you know that your links to the other networks are low-bandwidth.  Generic Linux boxes don't make particularly efficient routers.  Real routers that happen to be running Linux generally won't be using Linux networking for the fast path, so the files you listed won't help in that case.  And if those files are on your local host rather than the router, then they're not going to be of any help.

The only thing that will help if it's a real router is whatever management tools the router provides.  Most home routers don't provide this info.  Commercial routers might, but using a proprietary interface, or else an SNMP MIB.  The SNMP interface MIB has an entry for output queue length, but it's deprecated, probably because reality is more complex than a single number for an interface (since routers often queue per flow rather than per interface.)  Perhaps there's another MIB that would help.

`/sys/class/net/(interface)/tx_queue_len` is a configuration parameter, telling you what the max queue length is, in packets, on your local system.  Unless you can see this on the router, and your router is just using Linux networking, this isn't helpful.

To further complicate matters, TCP uses a variety of methods (including but not limited to explicit congestion notification) to avoid having packets buffered up in routers between the source and destination.  When it's working ideally, the maximum congestion in any router on the path is averaging one packet!  The reason for this is that it's best to have a minimum of packets buffered in the network, as long as the busiest router always has a packet ready to go.  Bloating queues in the network just increases end-to-end delays without adding any performance benefit.  This is pretty obvious but a lot of science and experimentation went into deriving it.

So, it seems you're trying to monitor something that should really always max out around 1, if things are working correctly.  (Note that the control algorithms in TCP work even if there are lots of unrelated TCP connections sharing any of the routers on the path.  They fail when any of the TCP implementations aren't using the methods, and they tend to fail by throttling back and letting the hogs get the bandwidth, sadly.)

So, my guess is that you're trying to do something that isn't really fruitful even if it is possible.

One thing that you can do is periodically ping the other end and low-pass filter the response time.  You won't know which direction is experiencing congestion, but you'll get a clue when there is congestion.

Comment: I forgot to mention that this router is not mine and it is running OpenWrt (I cannot change it to another router). Also, the monitorization is limited to a lab environment (not a real life setup) consisting of a router forwarding multiple clients' packets to the Internet (or should I call it, external network). I am actually already pinging the Internet and storing latency information, but I wanted another metric to "level up" my monitoring program. And I mean, I think it would be relevant to know when the router's queue is getting closer to its maximum capacity, but I might be thinking wrong

Comment: You should add the OpenWrt fact to your OP and add the `OpenWrt` tag, to increase the likelihood of getting advice from someone who knows about it.

Comment: Persistent queue depths > 1 means that the TCP endpoints aren't working properly (and mean that latencies are higher than they should be.)  Make sure ECN is enabled on your hosts.  See if you can get ECN enabled on the router, which usually requires configuring queuing such as WRED.  Without queuing configured, there will be no single answer to your question (queue depth.)  With it, ECN on the router is an option and helps TCP run efficiently, minimizing latency on intervening routers.  Read the wikipedia article on ECN and RFC3168 for a clearer understanding. Understand what you measure!

Comment: ECN must be negotiated between endpoints, and the only element I can control in my environment is the OpenWrt router. I can't retrieve, and don't really need, information on TCP endpoints, I must acquire queue occupation information only using the router... This is because I need information on congestion only on the outgoing interface of the router (the one connecting to the Internet). I don't really understand why I would have to configure WRED on my router, could you please elaborate?

Comment: In commercial routers with high speed network processing engines, there's an input and output queue per interface but these are kept as short as possible; buffering happens in the NPU's Traffic Manager.  Input packets get read into the NPU ASAP so they can be managed.  They're hashed to flows and each flow is kept in order, but there is no queue per flow unless RED is configured.  However, OpenWrt may be different, as it's not a high-speed router.